# Angular directive for a stack of sticky-compact elements

Tags: css, angularjs, sticky

I am looking for a good angular directive, that would handle sticky elements and append a compact class to it once they are out of the view...

so imagine a header element on a website, that has a normal height of 200px;... but when you start scrolling down, you would FIRST make the heater sticky (position fixed - top: 0) but when you scroll down for more than 200 px (I guess) you would append a "compact" class to it, so you would than see a compacted version of the header on top - lets say 70px;. This is quite established behaviour with modern [responsive] websites.

Which is fine and easy enough. The problem is when you want to stack more elements on top...

So to better explain myself... you would have the mentioned header with mentioned behavior... but further down on the page you would have a table, with it's theader row... and you would like to stack that on top, but after the header... and only when you scroll pass it...and also with "COMPACT" behavior (but not necessarily)

and imagine you would have some navigation even further down (tabs for example)... and you would like to stuck them on top as well, but only after the header and table...

so the directive would need to calculate the fixed top position depending on the elements already stuck there and if they are a compact version of themselves or not...

plus it should consider also the (css) animation bit (lets say you would put a transition animation on height of the element... so the transition of full to compact is smooth)

Anything similar out there already? I don't think this is something new in terms of expected behavior...so there must be some solutions out there already.

anyone?

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an older topic, but I think I've a proper solution.

I'm the creator of [Angular Sticky](https://github.com/harm-less/angular-sticky) and already have this feature implemented.

You can view the demo displaying with most of what you're asking [right here](http://harm-less.github.io/angular-sticky/#/demo/sticky-stack). The "collections" demo has more header like behavior though.

There is however some smart CSS that needs to be done to make the compacting happen, but I think it should be possible with the current functionalities of the plugin. I might need to look into this too anyway as I can imagine it can be a popular request.

Comment: Major deterrent from using "Angular Sticky" for me was that it works only when body is scrolled. It [doesn't work with inner scrolling areas](https://github.com/harm-less/angular-sticky/issues/13)

Answer (score 0):

[ng-sticky](https://github.com/d-oliveros/ngSticky) could do with a little mod.

It has a body sticky class so you can change the behavior of the whole page after an element became sticky.

### UPD1

As I stated before a little update of ngSticky would do the trick.

So I decided to do such changes
Here is my fork of ngsticky on [Github](https://github.com/Kvadratni/ngMultipleSticky)

It is still very WIP and I'm planning to contribute it to the main ngSticky project when done.
But before that( and continuing my work on it) I wanted to check with you if this is the behavior you are expecting.

Any response will be helpful.

Comment: I tried the sticky, but it deals only with the first bit... not really helpful with a stack of sticky elements (and the offset that changes to the element prior in the stack) - and specially not with the part when the prior elements become a compact versions of themselves (so even less offset)

Comment: I think is moving into the right direction... the logic on compact, in my opinion, should be more dynamic and not based on the static offset - specially on a responsive site...

I've been working on an internal solution for days now, having a stack of sticky elements, including table headers.... the logic I implemented is to first apply the compact class, get the elements' new height, and remove the compact class... so then you have a more dynamic offset.... not the most elegant, but does the trick...

Comment: now working to have table headers stuck as well, and retaining the columns width.... and remove being sticky when you scroll down pass the table...

Comment: @DS_web_developer you can use `confine ` for the removing part. it works great for me. Dynamic offset is planned but as I said it is an early demo ( 3-4 hours of work). thanks for the feedback

Comment: ng-sticky does not update width of element on resize